# Accessing Stored Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object "Driver" defined at the beginning of my script as such:

```
function Driver(draw, name) {
    this.draw = draw;
    this.name = name;
}
```

I'm using this bit of JQuery to create new drivers:

```
var main = function () {
   // add driver to table
    $('#button').click(function ( ) {
        var name = $('input[name=name]').val();
        var draw = $('input[name=draw]').val();
        var draw2 = "#"+draw;
        var name2 = "driver"+draw
        console.log(draw2);
        console.log(name2);
        if($(name2).text().length > 0){
            alert("That number has already been selected");}
        else{$(name2).text(name);
            var name2 = new Driver(draw, name);}
});
```

That part is working great. However, when I try later on to access those drivers, the console returns that it is undefined:

```
    $('.print').click(function ( ) {
        for(var i=1; i<60; i++){
            var driverList = "driver"+i;
            if($(driverList.draw>0)){
            console.log(driverList);
            console.log(driverList.name);
}
```

If you're interested, I've uploaded the entire project I'm working on to this site:

http://precisioncomputerservices.com/slideways/index.html

Basically, the bottom bit of code is just to try to see if I'm accessing the drivers in the correct manner (which, I'm obviously not). Once I know how to access them, I'm going to save them to a file to be used on a different page.

Also a problem is the If Statement in the last bit of code. I'm trying to get it to print only drivers that have actually been inputed into the form. I have a space for 60 drivers, but not all of them will be used, and the ones that are used won't be consecutive.

Thanks for helping out the new guy.

Comment: `if($(driverList.draw>0)){` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: And if `name2` is something like `"driver1"`, `$(name2)` won't select anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a variable to refer to a variable as you have done.

In your case one option is to use an key/value based object like

```
var drivers = {};
var main = function () {
    // add driver to table
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var name = $('input[name=name]').val();
        var draw = $('input[name=draw]').val();
        var draw2 = "#" + draw;
        var name2 = "driver" + draw
        console.log(draw2);
        console.log(name2);
        if ($(name2).text().length > 0) {
            alert("That number has already been selected");
        } else {
            $(name2).text(name);
            drivers[name2] = new Driver(draw, name);
        }
    });


    $('.print').click(function () {
        for (var i = 1; i < 60; i++) {
            var name2 = "driver" + i;
            var driver = drivers[name2];
            if (driver.draw > 0) {
                console.log(driver);
                console.log(driver.name);
            }
```