# JavaScript - Object not adding to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

(FYI: Thanks again for helping a newbie trying to self-teach).

I'm trying to recreate an array that was parsed out of session storage.

```
var entries = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('entries'));
console.log(entries);
var stDrivArray = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('entrynames')); //retrieve from storage
var stDrivArray2 = $.makeArray(stDrivArray); //turn into an array, but gives each entry in the array the name "object". They need to become "Driver"

//this is the attempt to make them become Drivers
for(var i=0; i<stDrivArray2.length; i++){
    console.log(stDrivArray2[i]);
    var draw2=stDrivArray2[i].draw;
    var name2=stDrivArray2[i].name;
    var name3 = "."+"driver"+stDrivArray2[i].draw;
    Driver[name3] = new Driver(draw2, name2);
    console.log(Driver[name3]);
    //DrivArray.push(Driver[name3]);
    DrivArray[DrivArray.length]=Driver[name3];
};
console.log(DrivArray);
```

An interesting issue: When I print `Driver[name3]` to the console, it prints correctly. For example:

`Driver {draw: "5", name: "David Dubczak"}`

I'm trying to add each object to the `DrivArray`, but when I print out `DrivArray` afterwards, this is what prints:

```
0: Driver
     draw: undefined
     name: undefined
```

However, it does print one object for each driver in the script! It's just the values are undefined. This seems strange, since the object is being created correctly, but for some reason the values are not being added correctly to the keys in the array (I hope I'm using the right vocabulary).

It's especially strange since I'm using the exact same technique to add the same object to the same array on a previous page (hence the need to store and retrieve from session storage) and it's working just fine.

Thoughts?

Thanks again.

Comment: `Driver[name3] = new Driver(draw2, name2);` ---- why do you put it to an undefined object at first place?

Comment: I used the same format that was recommended to me in this post: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29464122/accessing-stored-object

It worked perfectly, but I'll admit to being at a loss as to why.

Comment: It's not the same. I would say I don't even see how you could think of `Driver[name3]` from that answer. I highly recommend you learn JS basics first before you continue.

Comment: And it is working to create the Driver object - it's printing to the console correctly elsewhere in my script.

Comment: Please learn how to work with JS variables before you dive into much more complex topics (like constructor functions).

Comment: In the previous post, the suggestion was to create a global object, named 'drivers'.  That is what this line does:  var drivers = {};   Then when you use the form  'drivers[x] = new Driver();', you are adding each new Driver as a parameter.  It looks like this:  drivers { x:  { draw: ..., name: ...}, y: {}, ... }.  Otherwise known as a Dictionary or a Map.

Comment: Here, you don't need to add the new Drivers as parameters to the global driver object.  As suggested below, you can simply add them to the DrivArray[] directly.   Adding them to the Driver object, while legal, is messy and doesn't make for maintainable code.

Comment: Ah, great explanation. That really helps me figure out what's going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i dont really know what part you expect `name3` to have

but replace

```
Driver[name3] = new Driver(draw2, name2);
console.log(Driver[name3]);
//DrivArray.push(Driver[name3]);
DrivArray[DrivArray.length]=Driver[name3]
```

with

```
DrivArray[DrivArray.length]= new Driver(draw2, name2);
```

and it should work

Comment: That gives me an error of 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]`

Comment: @DavidDubczak they way you try to "learn" programming does not work and will not lead to become a developer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with. The Array is printing to the console correctly now.

```
    for(var i=0; i<stDrivArray2.length; i++){
    console.log(stDrivArray2[i]);
    var draw2=stDrivArray2[i].draw;
    var name2=stDrivArray2[i].name;
    var name3 = "."+"driver"+stDrivArray2[i].draw;
    Driver[name3] = new Driver(draw2, name2, 0, 0);
    console.log(Driver[name3]);
    //DrivArray.push(Driver[name3]);
    DrivArray[DrivArray.length]=Driver[name3];
    //DrivArray[] = new Driver(Draw3, name2);
};
console.log(DrivArray);
```

Also, I added two more values to the object, so the object is now:

```
function Driver(draw, name, points, order) {
this.draw = draw;
this.name = name;
this.points = points;
this.order = order;
```

}